# plot data from a txt file

Tags: python

I would like to plot data from a txt file to a graph:

```
13/7/2009 12:50:50   147425826 0 4716298 36645030 3757926 228230
13/7/2009 13:5:1     147517368 0 4717954 36687455 3761270 228375
13/7/2009 13:10:0    147550312 0 4718599 36701448 3762634 228437
```

The date should be the x axis and the remaining columns should be the y axis (in separated lines).

Comment: Do you need to use Python? Could use `gnuplot`

Answer (score 1):

one of the best python package for plotting data is [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/).

then, you only have to parse your input file:

```
import time

data = []
for line in open('input.txt'):
    date,time,*samples = line.split()
    data.append((time.strptime(str.join(' ', (date, time)), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'), samples))
```

then use matplotlib to plot the data...

*(the above parsing code may be rewritten using a list comprehension, which may be more memory efficient since it will implicitly  use iterators and lazy evaluation instead of storing the whole data in the list)*

Comment: hi thanks for the fast answer but my problem is how to use matplotlib to plot it

Comment: well, unfortunately, you will have to read the documentation. i used this package many times with great success, but writing a tutorial article on matplotlib will be way too long and would not fit in this answer. have a look at the [plot_date() function](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date) for a starting point.